# how to update contact in flutter

Tags: flutter

I use contact service to update my contacts, but it does not work, the contact number is remove. i use contact service `contacts_service: ^0.4.6`

```
Future updateContact(Contact contact, part) async{
    
    Iterable<Item> phones = contact.phones;
    List newPhones = [];

    for(var phone in phones){
      String newPhone;
      if(part == 0) newPhone = "22489653214";
      else newPhone = "22489653214";

      newPhones.add(Item(label: phone.label, value: newPhone));
    }

    contact.phones = newPhones.map((e) => e);
    await ContactsService.updateContact(contact);
  }
```

Comment: Can you add an error to the question?

Comment: I have not an error

Comment: I see contact name but contact number is remove

Comment: i am facing same issue, my contact is getting removed when i called contactUpdate method, anyone who knows kindly help !